# Working with ocaml Lwt sockets

Tags: sockets, ocaml

I have been on learning Ocaml for a week, some things got clear, the others rather not.
I'm trying to compose a simple Tic-Tac-Toe server accepting connections via telnet. Just for a word.
I have to use Lwt and rigth now it seems for me a darken place because I had faced too much of language pecularities.
The begining of the code:

```
let sock = Lwt_unix.socket Unix.PF_INET Unix.SOCK_STREAM 0

let setting_up_server_socket =  
    let sockaddr = (Unix.ADDR_INET(Unix.inet_addr_of_string "127.0.0.1", 23233)) in
    Lwt_unix.set_close_on_exec sock;
    Lwt_unix.setsockopt sock Unix.SO_REUSEADDR true;
    Lwt_unix.bind sock sockaddr;
    Lwt_unix.listen sock 20
```

OK, that's clear. The server socket is set to listen for clients connections. Let's try to get a first guest:

```
let handle_income = 
    Lwt_unix.accept sock;;
```

Seems to be clear, but:

```
val handle_income : (Lwt_unix.file_descr * Lwt_unix.sockaddr) Lwt.t = <abstr>
```

Here I'm stacked. I don't know even how to send a message to client socket.
Unlike general Unix.accept it returns ('a * 'b) Lwt.t. Some questions:

1. How can I get pure client "Lwt_unix.file_descr" from that?
2. ('a * 'b) Lwt.t. is a tuple belonging to Lwt.t object, isn't it? Or it just a field? I am confused at all.

P.S. Sorry if my English is not acceptable. I was learning it long time ago. As the question is already asked please give a piece of advise, where I can get the best information about Ocaml. The best a mean short/clearness. Due reading O'REILLY I instantly forget what I was reading 5 min ago because it's never clear what this or that the author talking about is used for. Ocaml is quite different with Java and JS I had started with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A value of type `'a Lwt.t` represents a thread that will evaluate to a value of type `'a` once it is ready (or to an error is something went wrong). The only way to get `'a` from `'a Lwt.t` is to bind it to another function, that will be called as soon, as `'a Lwt.t` thread is finished and data is ready. You can bind with `Lwt.bind` function, also available in an infix notation `>>=`.

For example:

```
let process_client fd = 
  Lwt_unix.accept fd >>= fun (cli,sock) ->
  let chan = Lwt_io.(of_fd ~mode:output cli) in
  Lwt_io.fprintf chan "hi there, and bye!" >>= fun () ->
  Lwt_io.close chan
```

This uses infix notation, you can rewrite it more verbose:

```
let reply chan = 
  Lwt_io.fprintf chan "hi there, and bye!"

let finish chan = Lwt_io.close chan

let create_chan = Lwt_io.(of_fd ~mode:output cli)

let process_client fd = 
  let accept_t = Lwt_unix.accept fd in
  let chan_t = Lwt.map accept_t create_chan in
  let reply_t = Lwt.bind accept_t reply in 
  Lwt.bind reply_t finish
```

Where `_t` designates `thread`. I.e., `accept_t` is a thread that will eventually return a pair of a file descriptor and a socket address. `chan_t` is a thread that will return a channel (for doing buffered io).

`Lwt` also comes with a support for special syntax. Actually with support for two syntaxes, the old with camlp4 and a newer one with ppx. In old syntax, one can write the `process_client` function as follows:

```
let process_client fd = 
  lwt (cli,sock) = Lwt_unix.accept fd in
  let chan = Lwt_io.(of_fd ~mode:output cli) in
  lwt () = Lwt_io.fprintf chan "hi there, and bye!" in
  Lwt_io.close chan
```

There `lwt` is a special form of `let` that not only binds names to values, but also waits for them to evaluate.

I hope that I answered all your questions. You may also find this [library](https://github.com/ivg/socket) interesting.

P.S. I didn't test the code, so if you have any issues, don't hesitate to ask.

P.P.S. I left a proper `shutdown` procedure, to keep code simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the things got much clearer. Let me ask another question: what's wrong about "Lwt_io.fprintf chan "hi there, and bye!""? Lwt_io.fprintf is not able to accept a "raw" string via function argument demanding ('a, unit, string, unit Lwt.t) format4. Is there a beautiful way to do that? Is that connected with native Unix.fprintf (or something) demanding "str" 0 3 [] etc? Thanks again

Comment: Upd. I tried Lwt_io.fprintf chan "%s\n" msg;; Seems to be working. It's still hard to get where it's neccesary to use Lwt, and where not)