# OCaml: how to read in a socket inside a Lwt thread

Tags: ocaml

suppose that there is a thread with a simple server that accepts a connection and another thread with a client.

```
let () =
  let sock = create_socket () in
    let threads = Lwt.join [create_server sock; sock_read sock] in
      Lwt_main.run threads
```

I tried to write the client like this:

```
let sock_recv sock maxlen =
  let str = Bytes.create maxlen in
  let recvlen  = Lwt_unix.recv sock str 0 maxlen [] in
  String.sub str 0 recvlen

let sock_read sock =
  let answer = sock_recv sock 512 in
    Lwt_io.write_line Lwt_io.stdout answer
```

I have an error that says :

```
File "lwt_server.ml", line 38, characters 19-26:
Error: This expression has type int Lwt.t
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

Which is related to this : `String.sub str 0 recvlen`

With the answer of this question( [Working with ocaml Lwt sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102949/working-with-ocaml-lwt-sockets)) I understand that in order to get the `int` value, I have to create a thread with the `bind` function or the infix operator `>>=` followed by an anonymous function. But all my tries failed miserably.

So how can I read a socket in a Lwt thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sock_recv` and `sock_read` functions should be written this way:

```
let sock_recv sock maxlen =
  let str = Bytes.create maxlen in
  Lwt_unix.recv sock str 0 maxlen [] >>= fun recvlen ->
  Lwt.return (String.sub str 0 recvlen)

let sock_read sock =
  sock_recv sock 512 >>= fun answer ->
  Lwt_io.write_line Lwt_io.stdout answer
```

I.e., you replace occurrences of `let x = foo in` by `foo >>= fun x ->` when `foo` returns an Lwt value. But the right hand side of `>>=` must also return an Lwt value (hence the call to `Lwt.return` in `sock_recv`).